# Working with a Non-hijabi Non-Mahram in a science project

Tags: halal-haram, non-mahram

Is it haram for me to work with a non-mahram non-hijabi woman for a college science project.

To give you context: There'll be 2 other male member in my team. I'm not being forced to work w/ her. I can choose to work with other men if I want. But she's really good at what she does better than all the other male students available.

I don't plan to talk with her about anything except only the project stuff. And I'm confident I can lower my gaze InshaAllah

Here "work" means she will do research with me, develop the project then we have to make a video about it that's it.